# MLflow Experiments Tracking : local (dev tools - vscode) to databricks workspace

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

I had configured my databricks workspace in local using,

`databricks configure --profile <profile_name> --token`

by which I am able to list the clusters and create secret scope.

But I am unable to create mlflow experiments. I had set the tracking uri to "databricks" and also tested with "databricks/<profile_name" and tested but i am unable to create or track any experiments on my databricks workspace.

I get this following error;

`from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient client = MlflowClient() mlflow.set_tracking_uri("databricks") experiment =  client.get_experiment_by_name('/Shared/test')`

MlflowException: API request to endpoint was successful but the response body was not in a valid JSON format. Response body: '<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/><title>Databricks - Sign In</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=960"/><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><script defer="defer" src="/login/login.0ceb14c0.js"></script></head><body class="light-mode"><uses-legacy-bootstrap><div id="login-page"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap></body></html>'

Could someone help me on what I am missing here?

I am expecting to create/track mlflow experiements in databricks workspace via dev-tools(vscode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem while trying to load a model from model registry with mismatching versions (client 1.22.0).

I had to downgrade the client version to make it work.

Downgraded first the client to 1.21 and then server to 1.20

Refer - https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/mlflow.html#operation/transition-model-version-stage